# Restore in-app purchased failed

Tags: xcode, swift, in-app-purchase

Even I try to restore my purchase and cancel it after the first step it will still unlock my premium stoff. Where is the bug?

```
 @IBAction func restorePurchase(sender: UIButton) {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction

            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            switch prodID {
                case "xxxxxxxxxxxx":
                    purchaseedVoid()
                default:
                    print("IAP")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [Ray's tutorial about IAP](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial). I used his Purchase helper code to manage all my IAP. It works like a charm